# Get binary tree elements count at n-th depth using PHP

Tags: php, laravel, binary-tree

I have `users` table that represents a binary structure.

For example, the `user` has `left_id` and `right_id` that can be left and right node of the binary (`left_id` and `right_id` are the foreign keys for `users` table).

Also, the `user` has `parent_id` that is the above (root) node of the `user` element.

I need to count the binary elements count at n-th depth from root for one side (left or right).

For example, look at the image below.
The user has 3 elements at 2-depth for left side, and it has 7 elements at 3-th depth for the left side

[For example, the user has 3 elements at 2-depth for left side, and it has 7 elements at 3-th depth for the left side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imeI7.png)

I'm using Laravel framework for the application and tried to solve the problem:
I have a recursive function that counts elements of the user.

```
    private function followersCount($depth, &$step)
    {
        $sum = 0;
        // children attribute is the array of left and right elements
        foreach ($this->children as $child) {
            if ($step == $depth) return $sum; 
            $sum += $sum + $child->followersCount($depth, $step);
        }
        $step++;

        return $this->children->count() + $sum;
    }
```

But it iterates all the binary elements and cannot control `$step` variable.
Please, if you have any solutions, i would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Things i would adjust:

- It is not requried to send the step variabel by reference.
- Your `$step++` was after the loop, resulting in false values for the next recusion step
- the sum of your recursion has doubled as you used `$sum += $sum`

```
    private function followersCount($depth, $step)
    {
        $sum = 0;

        // children attribute is the array of left and right elements
        if ($step <= $depth) {
            $step++;
            foreach ($this->children as $child) {
                $sum += $child->followersCount($depth, $step);
            }
        }

        return $this->children->count() + $sum;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've modified my code as you suggest, but it didn't help.
I passed as an argument `$this->followersCount(3, 1)` and it returns 30, but it should return 7.
Can' understand why.

Comment: try to debug your trees, maybe you are one step to lower than you think. Maybe <= should be <, just test this.